# VB.NET Event for datetimepicker check changed

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datetimepicker

I can make a DateTimePicker so that it shows a checkbox to enable / disable the date.

I tried to find the event that is fire when the user changes this value, but I was unable to find it.

Is there no such event, or did I look in the wrong place?

Thank you!

Comment: doesnt the ValueChanged event fire?

Comment: Yes, it is. I tried this event during debugging, and it seems that VS2012 did not include it. Now that I restarted the app, it works. Thank you. Can you make your comment the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CheckBox` element is a way to detect whether the user has picked a date.  Since the DTP always has a valid date as the `.Value` it can be difficult to detect whether the user has selected a date; even harder if the date they want is already showing.

The `Checkbox` is meant to indicate 'yes, use this date'.  Whether they click the `CheckBox` or open the DTP, the `CheckBox` gets checked and the `ValueChanged` event should fire.

Note that of you use the less obnoxious form - `ShowUpDown` == True - you'll get one of these events each time the M-D-Y value changes due to a click or mouse wheel.